# How do I skip the serializer in Dancer2?

Tags: perl, dancer

My application is configured to send out JSON responses. I need to add an RSS (or anything else) endpoint to it. There are no no-op serializers, though it would be trivial to write one:

```
{ # do not use this lol
    package Dancer2::Serializer::ThisIsNotAnOkayThingToDo_Raw;
    use Moo;
    with 'Dancer2::Core::Role::Serializer';
    sub serialize { $_[1] }
    sub deserialize { $_[1] }
    1;
}

get '/mything/rss' => sub {
  my $rss = new XML::RSS (version => '2.0');
  $rss->channel(title => "Wharrgarbl");
  $rss->add_item(title => "Potato");
  send_as(ThisIsNotAnOkayThingToDo_Raw => $rss->as_string, {content_type => 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8'});
}
```

This, however, fails, claiming `__PACKAGE__::send_as` is not defined (but running `perldoc Dancer2::Manual` on the server does say `send_as` should be there).

```
# __PACKAGE__ is me redacting the sensitive out of the error message
Undefined subroutine &__PACKAGE__::send_as called at...
```

The documentation also claims that `send_as` uses `send_file`, so I tried to cut out the middleman:

```
get '/mything/rss' => sub {
  my $rss = new XML::RSS (version => '2.0');
  $rss->channel(title => "Wharrgarbl");
  $rss->add_item(title => "Potato");
  my $xml = $rss->as_string;
  send_file(\$xml, content_type => 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8');
}
```

This however goes through the serializer:

```
hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this) at .../site/lib/JSON.pm line 154.
```

What do?

Answer (score -1):

```
get '/mything/rss' => sub {
  # Calculate the result
  my $rss = ...;
  # Mark the request as successful
  status 200;
  # Be polite and set the content type
  content_type 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8';
  # Jam the result straight into the response object
  response->{content} = $rss;
  # Tell Dancer internals that the response has already been encoded 
  # (this is pretty much guaranteed to break in the future, regrettably)
  response->{is_encoded} = 1;
  # and return.
  return response;
}
```

---

Comment: this answer actually found by [Erik Jan Vos](https://nl.linkedin.com/in/erik-jan-vos-b2135366), please send precious internet karma his way

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Answer (score -1):

Use [send_as](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#send_as):

> Allows the current route handler to return specific content types to
>   the client using either a specified serializer or as html.

You can use it to specify your own serializer or just use the default html
 serializer but change the content-type for rss

```
use Dancer2;
set serializer => 'JSON';

get '/mything/rss' => sub {
  # Get your rss string 
  # ...
  my $xml = '<rss>content</rss>';
  send_as html => $xml , { content_type => 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8' };
}

dance;
```

Comment: send_as is literally the first thing I said I tried in my question.

Comment: Can you get the sample code to run outside of your application? The given example should be a fully working dancer2 app. In order to check if the problem is with your Dancer2 installation or something messed up in your app